# Ed25519 in smart contracts

Tags: solidity, evm

Is there a practical way (preferrably OSS library or implementation) to verify [Ed25519](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/) signatures in Solidity (compiled for and run on the EVM), in smart contracts?

**Update: I've created [EIP665](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-665.md)**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no native functions that provide ed25519 cryptographic operations.

Doing it in the EVM would require a substantial amount of processing, and being that:

> **Fast single-signature verification.** The software takes only ***273,364*** cycles to verify a signature on Intel's widely deployed Nehalem/Westmere lines of CPUs

I'm fairly certain that you'd quickly use up a lot of gas trying, most likely more than the maximum allowed.

In order to accomplish this, you'd need to start an EIP request, and convince the community that there's a valid and compelling use-case for implementing native signature verification in the server itself.

Specifically you'd want to explain in the EIP why the existing `ecsign` and `ecrecover` (ECDSA) routines aren't adequately suitable.

Comment: [EIP exists](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/665)

Comment: The link @benjaminion posted is a proposal for EIP 665, which hasn't been accepted yet. Seems to have stalled at December '17. Might be time to try and drum up some community support for it.

Comment: It also needs more content -- current description is quite short.

Comment: Thanks for the information! So even though it'll be slow/expensive, there is no known implementation in mere Solidity? rgd the Q of why: because ECDSA is inferior to Ed25519. From the crypto/algo (NIST/NSA may have deliberately designed for compromised curves) and technically (available implementations .. eg NaCl is side-channel resistant).

Comment: Yeah, but Ethereum is ECDSA based at a foundational level anyhow, so if it's compromised, the entire platform is suspect. I'm not arguing mind you, as I refuse to use ECDSA for any SSH and TLS keys I generate, but as an argument for an EIP, I doubt "cause NSA can crack it" will be sufficient as if NSA can crack it, they can bring the entire platform to it's knees.

Answer (score 3):

If it's an option, there's always something like [TrueBit](https://truebit.io/). That is, run the computation off-chain and use partitioned verification on-chain in the case that a computation is contested.

(There's a nice high-level description [here](https://medium.com/l4-media/making-sense-of-ethereums-layer-2-scaling-solutions-state-channels-plasma-and-truebit-22cb40dcc2f4) in the context of layer-2 scaling, and an intro [here](https://medium.com/@simondlr/an-intro-to-truebit-a-scalable-decentralized-computational-court-1475531400c3).)